# How to make Hibernate convert CLOB to a MySQL type

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, clob

In my code, a field of an entity class has a CLOB column. This works fine with Oracle but when I try to use MySQL as the database, it looks the CLOB type causes a problem because MySQL doesn't support CLOB. the console error is

13:35:27 ERROR [main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate
         You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CLOB,
        messageSubject longtext,
        senderEmailAddress varchar(255),
' at line 7 [main]

the java code snippet is:

```
@Column(length = 4000)
private String messageSubject;

@Column(columnDefinition = "CLOB")
private String messageBody;
```

and here is my entityfactory

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="runtime" />
    <property name="dataSource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/cggruntime" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class</prop>        

            <!-- Activate Second-Order Cache for Entities and Queries -->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

my question is that is there any way to configure hibernate so that CLOB can be automatically converted to other data types that MySQL supports (like Text)?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

MySQL absolutely does support CLOB.  The proper syntax to turn a Java String into a MySQL CLOB is as follows:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "columnNameForTheMysqlColumnHere")
private String messageBody;
```

Comment: is there any reference/links about MySQL supports CLOB? in the code you are using @Lob. this works but MySQL creates the column with the type "longtext". Actually if I add the "CLOB" in the column annotation like this:@Column(columnDefinition = "CLOB"), there is always error in the console" org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate
         You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CLOB, messageSubject longtext, senderEmailAddress varchar(255),". removing CLOB makes the code work.

Comment: CLOB as a columnDefinition is not supported.  MySQL only recognizes the `@Lob` annotation and then uses the context to determine if it is a clob or blob.  Define the column as a CLOB using basic MySQL Create query and then access it using the `@Lob` on a string.